# Collection error in `MeteorJs`?

Tags: meteor

I need help for I am insert date into `Collection` but **method not found** error is came.How to solve the error please help me here below is my code.

```
My Collection Name is : hcare_user = new Meteor.Collection('hcare'); 
Js code :
hcare_user.insert({
                         userid: userid, 
                         firstname : firstname,
                         lastname : lastname,
                                 bday: bday, 
                         bmonth : bmonth,
                         byear : byear,
                         phoneno:phoneno,
                         address : address,
                         city : city,
                         state:state,
                         zipcode: zipcode,
                         country : country,
                         ssn : ssn,
                         permissions:permissions
                          }
                     , function( error, result) 
                      { 
                        if ( error ) console.log ( "error ="+ error); //info about what went wrong
                        if ( result ) 
                        {
                            console.log ( "result="+result );//the _id of new object if successful
                            $('input[type="text"]').val('');
                            //$('input[type="radio"]').val('');
                            //$('input[type="date"]').val('');
                            alert("Sucessfully Created");
                                          }                 
                                    });
                                 }
                                 });
```

Error is:

```
error =Error: Method not found [404] @
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is usually the result of failing to declare a collection on the server.  Does this line appear in code that's running on both client **and** server?

```
hcare_user = new Meteor.Collection('hcare');
```

If not, you need to put it in a file that's outside the `client` or `server` directories and thus runs on both, and outside a `Meteor.isServer` or `Meteor.isClient` block.

If you only want a local collection (i.e. client only), you can change it to `hcare_user = new Meteor.Collection(null)`, and that should clear the error as well (although obviously you won't be inserting anything in persistent storage this way).